# Call to subprocess from within Python script, should adapt to variable content, and collect result

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following short command:

```
echo "6005600401" >> tst1 && evm disasm tst1
```

Which I'd like to issue inside of a Python script. In a sense it's similar to a simple Bash script, which just collects the output that arrives to the console. The real data it generates will look something like this:

```
6005600401
000000: PUSH1 0x05
000002: PUSH1 0x04
000004: ADD
```

I'd like to call this command from inside of a Python script and collect the data it generates into a representation that I can further process.

Accordingly I've been looking into subprocess management, and familiarizing myself with it in the `python` console like so:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
1
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
 status = subprocess.call("ls" + " -l", shell=True)
```

It seems that it wouldn't be difficult to put put that command into a Bash script and then execute that, but the kicker is I need to change the value that gets called by `echo`, based on the results of a different component, I also need to change the file that `echo` outputs to.

Then the question is, how to I call a sub-process from inside of a Python script that can accommodate changing variables, and then collect the result in a malleable data structure.

This can work

```
>>> status = subprocess.call("echo" + " '6005600401' >> tst2 && evm disasm tst2", shell=True)
6005600401
000000: PUSH1 0x05
000002: PUSH1 0x04
000004: ADD
```

But, is it the best way? How to collect the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just using `echo` to write to a file...why not just write to the file using Python?

```
with open('tst2', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write('6005600401\n')
status = subprocess.check_output(['evm', 'disasm', 'tst2'])
```

You could even wrap this up in a function:

```
def my_test_func(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(data)
        fd.write('\n')
    return subprocess.check_output(['evm', 'disasm', filename])

status = my_test_func('tst2', '6005600401')
```

Or instead of using named files, you could investigate the `tmpfile` module.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
check_out = lambda *cmd: subprocess.check_output(' '.join(map(str, cmd)), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).split()

c = 'echo {} >> {} && evm disarm {}'
```

Then you can just string format `c` and do:

```
check_out(c.format(*args))

['6005600401',
'000000: PUSH1 0x05',
'000002: PUSH1 0x04',
'000004: ADD']
```

You don't have to split it if you don't want to, but I agree with the poster above in terms of how to approach this.